# Shell StatusBar UserControl communication

Tags: wpf

I have a wpf main window as the application shell containing status bar and a tab control with two tab items.
I have also two User controls and their View Model objects using MVVM.
I placed each user control on a tab item in the application shell.

My question is, I want the user controls to update the status bar on the main shell. What is the best way to handle that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question.
I don't know exactly what is the best way to do it but this my guess:

To me, the application class (I mean an override of it) is not right place to put it because it is too central. The status is per Window (Dialog). 
Then, you could place it in the model of the Window but it is another bad idea (my opinion) because you will have to modify you model for something very virtual (status).
Personnaly, but I could be really wrong, I decided to declare a method in the parent window directly. Any model, if many, of any of my component that are part of that window could (preferably at initalization time) try to find the method (reflexion) and assign a delegate to it. Whenever you want to update the status you verifiy your delegate is not null and call it if its not. The delegate could be something like: SetStatus(string status). It's not perfect but it seems to respect hi cohesion and low coupling...

Hope it helps.
Eric

Answer (score 0):

**BXF** (Basic XAML Framework)

http://bxf.codeplex.com/

From the BXF Documentation Page:

> In its simplest form, Bxf acts as a message or request router from
>   application code to a presenter handler.
>
> The idea is that your application code, typically your viewmodel code,
>   needs to do a set of basic things:
>
> 1. Show views
> 2. List item
> 3. Show status information